# flipping sort: finding the minimum number of flipping list

Tags: python

I have a random integer list like below:

```
lis = [5,6,7,8,13,12,11,10,9]
```

if I use

```
lis.sort()
```

I can easily get the sorted list.

But what I am trying to do is to find the minimum number of flipping this list to find the sorted list in ascending order.

For instance, if I flip [13,12,11,10,9] from lis, then I would get a sorted list like this

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Since I flipped this list only once, so the output of my function would be 1.

if I have another list like

```
[5,50,1,3]
```

the result would be 2:

```
[5,50,1,3]
[1,50,5,3]
[1,3,5,50]
```

I am not sure where I can start =[

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to only use flipping of a contiguous subrange of the list or would you allow flipping of disparate elements ?   In any case, there could be a very large number of of flipping combinations and you will likely need a goal seeking algorithm with backtracking to explore them all.

Comment: @AlainT. Thank you for your time! It would be a contiguous subrange, and the length of the list should not be greater than 8, so it would not have that large number =]